# How to return every nth item in a list for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list that is in a similar format as this:

```
list1 = ['random words go', 'here and','the length varies','blah',
         'i am so confused', 'lala lala la']
```

What code would be appropriate to return every 3rd item of the list, including the first word? This is the expected output:

```
["random", "here", "length", "i", "confused", "la"]
```

I am thinking that I should use the split function, but I don't know how to do this. Can someone also explain how I can make it so the whole list isn't in 'parts' like that? Rather, how can I turn it into one long list, if that makes sense.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to return list of every n'th item in a larger list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list)

Comment: @dnozay not exactly, the OP is explaining it poorly though.

Comment: yes, I see that now, the other question is still very relevant for one part of the problem.

Comment: What he really wants is to join each phrase as a string, separate by words again into a list, then pick out certain ones. Poorly worded.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably the most readable way to do it:

```
>>> list1 = ['random words go', 'here and','the length varies','blah', 'i am so confused', 'lala lala la']
>>> result = ' '.join(list1).split()[::3]
['random', 'here', 'length', 'i', 'confused', 'la']
```

or without joining and splitting the list again:

```
from itertools import chain
result = list(chain.from_iterable(s.split() for s in list1))[::3]
```

then you can just join the result:

```
>>> ' '.join(result)
'random here length i confused la'
```

Comment: @BedSheets `' '.join(...)`

Answer (score 3):

Go for:

```
list1 = ['random words go', 'here and','the length varies','blah', 'i am so confused', 'lala lala la']

from itertools import chain, islice    
sentence = ' '.join(islice(chain.from_iterable(el.split() for el in list1), None, None, 3))
# random here length i confused la
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[word for item in list1 for word in item.split()][0::3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another memory efficient version

```
>>> list1 = ['random words go', 'here and','the length varies','blah', 'i am so confused', 'lala lala la']
>>> from itertools import chain, islice
>>> ' '.join(islice(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, list1)), 0, None, 3))
'random here length i confused la'
```

Answer (score 0):

To turn it into one long list:

```
>>> list6 = []
>>> for s in list1:
...   for word in s.split():
...     list6.append(word)
... 
>>> list6
['random', 'words', 'go', 'here', 'and', 'the', 'length', 'varies',     'blah', 'i', 'am', 'so', 'confused', 'lala', 'lala', 'la']
>>>
```

Then you can do the slicing as suggested with [::3]

```
>>> list6[::3]
['random', 'here', 'length', 'i', 'confused', 'la']
```

If you want it in one string:

```
>>> ' '.join(list6[::3])
'random here length i confused la'
>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> list1 = ['random words go', 'here and','the length varies','blah', 'i am so confused', 'lala lala la']
>>> result = ' '.join(list1).split()[::3]
['random', 'here', 'length', 'i', 'confused', 'la']
```