# Plotting only years on x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My code currently looks like:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

ax = plt.gca()

plt.plot(new_stripped_df["Month"],new_stripped_df['(ii) Monthly difference, Natural log of the Exchange Rate per U.S. Dollar'])

plt.title('Monthly Growth in Nominal Exchange rates',fontdict={'fontname':'Calibri','fontsize':15})

plt.xlabel("Date",fontdict={'fontname':'Calibri','fontsize':10})

plt.ylabel("Log Change",fontdict={'fontname':'Calibri','fontsize':10})

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Which returns:

[image: Graph]

As you can see the x axis tickers are unreadable and I want to include only every 5 years from 1960 to 1990 on the x axis. `new_stripped_df["Month"]` is in format: Jan 1960 all the way up to Dec 1990.

Comment: It looks like you are using pandas dataframe. In this case, it would be easier to use the pandas plotting methods, because they automatically fit the x/y ticks. 
Please also have a look at this question, whether it answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25279475/matplotlib-pyplot-tick-control-and-showing-date

Comment: Note that `new_stripped_df["Month"]` should be in the pandas datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the x-axis data is `datetime`. Then, you need to use [`YearLocator()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.YearLocator).

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, DateFormatter

# Data
df = pd.DataFrame({"val": list(range(1200))})
df["dates"] = [datetime.today() - timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 24000, 20)]

# Plot
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = [12, 7])
ax.plot(df["dates"], df["val"])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(5))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%Y"))
```