# Python: Loop Dictionary, Two keys at a time

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working on a program that requires me to loop a dictionary two keys at a time. Here's a simple representation of my dictionary.

```
my_dict = {
    'LAP0-1': 146.48,
    'LAP1-1':44.11,
    'LAP2-1':25.54,
    'LAP3-1':75.29,
    'LAP5-2':85.76,
    'LAP6-2':46.87
}

# loop dictionary 1 key at a time
for k,v in my_dict:
    print k + " | " + v;
```

I know if I had a list, I could loop the items 2 at a time like so:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    print my_list[i] + " | " + my_list[i+1];
```

But is it possible to loop the dictionary two keys at a time?

I want to print out the following in a loop:

```
LAP0-1 | 146.48 ; LAP1-1 | 44.11
LAP1-1 | 44.11 ; LAP2-1 | 25.54
LAP2-1 | 75.29 ; LAP3-1 | 85.76
LAP5-2 | 85.76 ; LAP6-2 | 46.87
```

Another solution I thought of but won't for my case is this:

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list), 2):
    print my_dict[my_list[i]] + " | " my_dict[my_list[i+1]];
```

where `my_list[i]` is`'LAP0-1'` and `my_list[i+1]` is `'LAP1-1'`. It just seems inefficient having to store keep 2 data structures like that. How do I loop a dictionary two keys at a time?

Comment: for skip every k element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list

Comment: Are you expecting the dict to remember what order you wrote the entries in? Dicts are semantically unordered; they're key-value lookup structures. Iterating over them may produce an entirely different order from the order you wrote. If what you really want is a sequence of ordered pairs, a list of tuples is frequently a better data structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import tee

my_dict = OrderedDict([
    ('LAP0-1', 146.48),
    ('LAP1-1', 44.11),
    ('LAP2-1', 25.54),
    ('LAP3-1', 75.29),
    ('LAP5-2', 85.76),
    ('LAP6-2', 46.87)
])

# pairwise() from Itertools Recipes
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

for (key1, value1), (key2, value2) in pairwise(my_dict.items()):
    print("{} | {} ; {} | {}".format(key1, value1, key2, value2))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LAP0-1 | 146.48 ; LAP1-1 | 44.11
LAP1-1 | 44.11 ; LAP2-1 | 25.54
LAP2-1 | 25.54 ; LAP3-1 | 75.29
LAP3-1 | 75.29 ; LAP5-2 | 85.76
LAP5-2 | 85.76 ; LAP6-2 | 46.87
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with just a dictionary, as dictionaries are unsorted. However, you could get a sorted list of the keys, and go from there:

```
import itertools

keys = sorted(my_dict.keys(), key=lambda k:int(k.split('-')[0][3:]))
keys, ks = tee(keys)
next(ks, None)

for k1,k2 in zip(keys, ks):
    print("{} | {} ; {} | {}".format(k1, my_dict[k1], k2, my_dict[k2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track with your use of `range()`, but you are correct in that it returns a list, which isn't very efficient if your dataset is large. You can mitigate that concern by using [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), which returns an object that can be iterated over.

```
>>> my_dict = {
...     'LAP0-1': 146.48,
...     'LAP1-1':44.11,
...     'LAP2-1':25.54,
...     'LAP3-1':75.29,
...     'LAP5-2':85.76,
...     'LAP6-2':46.87
... }
>>> keys = my_dict.keys()
>>> for i in xrange(0, len(keys), 2):
...     key1 = keys[i]
...     key2 = keys[i+1]
...     print key1, key2, my_dict[key1], my_dict[key2]
...
LAP3-1 LAP0-1 75.29 146.48
LAP5-2 LAP1-1 85.76 44.11
LAP6-2 LAP2-1 46.87 25.54
```

You're still creating a new list of keys, but that's probably okay.

EDIT: You should also probably be aware that dictionaries are *unordered*. If you want ordered dictionaries, you must use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), which isn't as fast.

Comment: I fixed a typo and added printing the values.

Comment: The questioner's concern with the `range` thing doesn't seem to be `range`; it seems to be the separate `my_list` list. Also, `keys()` isn't guaranteed to return the keys in any particular order.

Comment: Well, I cut down on the number of new lists being created from 2 to 1.

Answer (score 1):

This will print out what you're looking for:

```
keys_in_order = sorted(my_dict.keys())

for i in range(len(keys_in_order) - 1):
     print(keys_in_order[i] + " | " + str(my_dict[keys_in_order[i]]) + " ; " + keys_in_order[i + 1] + " | " + str(my_dict[keys_in_order[i + 1]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Supplementary answer: as noted in other answers, a vanilla dictionary has no defined ordering of its keys. However, the `collections` module provides `OrderedDict` which does remember the order in which its keys are defined and lets you iterate over it in this order

```
>>> keys=("A", "nice", "sunny", "day", )
>>> d={}
>>> for key in keys: d[key]=1
... 
>>> for key in d: print (key)
... 
sunny
day
nice
A

>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d=OrderedDict()
>>> for key in keys: d[key]=1
... 
>>> for key in d: print (key)
... 
A
nice
sunny
day
```