# Selenium xpath each element 5

Tags: selenium, xpath

I use selenium and xpath selector. I know how to get a certain element. But how to use xpath to get each element 5?

Comment: Could please provide some scenario like HTML code and all?? and mention the programming language as well

Answer (score 1):

You can always solve it in your language of choice.

**Python**

For example, in Python, the extended slicing [allows to do it rather simply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list):

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tr")[0::5]
```

You can also use the [`position()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) and the `mod` operator:

```
//table/tr[position() mod 5 = 0]

driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tr[position() mod 5 = 0]")
```

---

**Java**

```
List<WebElement> elements=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[position() mod 5 = 0]"));
System.out.println(elements.size());
for (WebElement element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element.getText());
}
```

Comment: how to get every 5 starting from the second element?