# calculating every n amount of elements inside a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, math, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of size (201, 201) and i would like to calculate the mean of every 9 elements inside my list. For instance `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]`. I am expecting an output like this:

```
[5, 14, 23, 28, 45]
```

I followed this question for example but unfortunately the question deals with arrays: [Averaging over every n elements of a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15956309/averaging-over-every-n-elements-of-a-numpy-array)

I also followed this question: [Python - Average every "n" elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41933232/python-average-every-n-elements-in-a-list), but it calculates the mean from n+1 to n elements.

Im looking for a reproducible example for the list above for instance, that is a start for me i guess

Comment: What did you tried so far. It is not cool to let others write the entire code for you. Just add what you have tried so far and you show your willingness to at least try to find a solution.

Comment: [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) has an `axis` argument for this

Comment: alternative: `[sum(nums) / len(nums) for nums in nested_nums]`... result is `[5.0, 14.0, 23.0, 31.5, 40.5]`, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is by `map` with a `lambda` function:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]
means = list(map(lambda x: np.mean(x), A))
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need:

```
my_list = [[1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], 
       [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27], 
       [28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35], 
       [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45]]

avg_list = []

for item in my_list:
    avg = int(sum(item)/len(item))
    avg_list.append(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `statistics` library has a [`mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) function for this as well.

```
from statistics import mean

averages = list(map(mean, my_list))
```

Results:

```
[5, 14, 23, 31.5, 40.5]
```