# Take every nth block from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Given a list:

```
import string
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
```

What is the Pythonic way to return every *nth* block of *m* elements?  Note that this is different from just returning [every *nth* element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list).

Desired result of taking every *1st of 3 blocks of 3 elements* (take 3, skip 6, take 3, skip 6...):

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
```

I can get to this as:

```
import itertools
s1 = a[::9]
s2 = a[1::9]
s3 = a[2::9]    
res = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(s1,s2, s3)))
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fixed order of select and skip, you can wrap indices taking the modulo on the total length of the window (9 here) and select only those beneath the given threshold, 3:

```
lst = [x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i % 9 < 3]
print(lst)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
```

You can make this into a function that makes it more intuitive to use:

```
def select_skip(iterable, select, skip):
    return [x for i, x in enumerate(iterable) if i % (select+skip) < select]  

print(select_skip(a, select=3, skip=6))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
```

Comment: Clever idea, but it takes a couple of brain cycles to see how the 'skip' is correct (6 == 9 - 3).  Might be better to wrap this logic in a helper function or generator expression.

Comment: @wim Yeah, should be more intuitive in a function.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps just writing a simple generator is the most readable

```
def thinger(iterable, take=3, skip=6):
    it = iter(iterable)
    try:
        while True:
            for i in range(take):
                yield next(it)
            for i in range(skip):
                next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return
```

This has the advantage of working even if the input is infinite, or not slicable (e.g. data coming in from a socket).

Comment: I think it may be the most approachable solution, maybe. I don't think it is the most readable in any way. Reading function names is usually nicer than reading syntax, and it is a more useful tool for a programmer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) is a third-party library that implements [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) and other helpful tools such as [`more_itertools.windowed`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.windowed).

```
>  pip install more_itertools
```

Code

```
import string

from more_itertools import windowed, flatten


m, n = 3, 6
list(flatten(windowed(string.ascii_lowercase, m, step=m+n)))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
```

`windowed` naturally steps one position per iteration.  Given a new step by advancing beyond the overlaps (`m`), the windows are appropriately determined.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using some [generic "chunks" recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks):

```
windows = chunks(original_iter, n=3)
```

Now that you've windowed you're data as you think of it, use [islice's second variant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) for its' 'step' capabilities:

```
# flattens the list as well using chain
result = chain.from_iterable(islice(windows, 0, None, 2))
```

Comment: You're relying on there to be a common multiple between the chunk and stride size. It might be cleaner to take chunks of 9, then slice them as needed.

Comment: Maybe, I just wanted to show the general approach. It can be varied easily I think.

Comment: This is less general, less easy to vary. That's why I commented.

Comment: I disagree, you stated the way to change it for a slightly different use case yourself. The point here is using almost-standard functions because we rarely do anything special. No need to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Assume the user now wants to take 4, skip 5. Or take 3, skip 7. How do they do that?

Comment: "take chunks of X, then slice them as needed."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension and create a function that does this for any skip, take and list values:

```
import string
import itertools
a = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
def everyNthBlock(a, take, skip):
  res = [a[i:i + take] for i in range(0, len(a) ,skip + take)]
  return list(itertools.chain(*res))

print(everyNthBlock(a, 3, 6))
#^^^^ => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
print(everyNthBlock(a, 4, 7))
#^^^^ => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using incomprehensible list comprehension :D

```
m, n = 3, 3
[elem for blockstart in range(0, len(a), m*n) for elem in a[blockstart:blockstart+n]]    
#> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'j', 'k', 'l', 's', 't', 'u']
```