# What am I doing wrong? It shows me that the list index is out of range

Tags: python, loops, range

I have a given list and I want to add all elements of that list with an odd index to the new list. Here is my code :

```
def odd_indices(lst):
  new_lst = [ lst[i] for i in lst if (i + 2) % 2 != 0 ]
  return new_lst
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for i in lst` returns the elements in `lst`, not its indices.

Comment: Why did you use `i + 2`, not `i`?

Comment: Do you want to keep the items with odd values (supposing that they are integers) or the ones with odd indices? In the latter case, you just want `lst[1::2]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pythonic way to return list of every nth item in a larger list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take the index instead of the value itself. The list `lst` contains values and not indices. `enumerate` helps generating indices. Do like below.

```
def odd_indices(lst):
  new_lst = [ v for i, v in enumerate(lst) if i% 2 != 0 ]
  return new_lst


print(odd_indices([1, 2, 4, 5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `enumerate` to work on index

```
>>> lst = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> [value for index, value in enumerate(lst) if index%2 != 0]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9] # output odd index values
```

**What is the mistake you have done?**

1. Iterating through list.
2. In each iteration you will get the element of that list.
3. you are using that element as the index of the list.

**EX:**

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

In above `lst`, the last element is 10.

```
lst[10] ---> which does not exists. # Throws out of index range error
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the list as follows:

```py
lst[1::2]
```

The general syntax is:

```py
list[start:end:step]
```

Answer (score 0):

in the list comprehension`[lst[i] for i in lst if (i + 2) % 2 != 0]` you iterate over items in the list and try to obtain elements from the original list with the respective index i if i+2 is odd.

as mentioned in other replies you can use enumerate to access index and element.

or you can simply use slicing

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> foo[1::2]
[2, 4]
```

Comment: so I can't access index and element at the same time? sorry for this question I'm very new to coding.

Comment: @Sumpfmaus, you can, using `enumerate()` - look at @shaikmoeed answer