# Get accurate number in list

Tags: python, list, operators

I search something in python to return a result from a list every 4 number

Here an example:

```
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]

I would like only [1,5,9,13,17]

So every 4 elements of list It returns me the result !
```

So I think I need use probably the operator %  but I don't know how I can do it.

Thanks !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to return list of every nth item in a larger list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list)

Comment: `list[::4]` - iterate through every fourth element in the list. Also `list` is a keyword, so don't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
list[::4]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
my_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17]
print(my_list[0::4])
```

and `list` is not a good name for your variable since it's a builtin function in python.