# calculate the mean of every nth list in a list of lists using a loop

Tags: python, list, numpy, loops

I am trying to calculate the mean of every nth list in a list of lists using a loop.
I have been able to do so without a loop, but this will prove laborious to do when the list of lists gets longer.

Im struggling to explain this so heres the code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


list = []
t_r = np.arange(0,8)
i = 0
a =[[0.98,1.93,2.99,4.01,4.92,6.00,7.08,7.67, 8.00],[0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,3],[0.93,1.99,2.99,3.91,4.82,6.03,7.01,8.00],[0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6],[0.88,2.09,3.01,4.11,5.65,7.12,8.00],[4,5,6,7,8,7,6]]
#########################
for t in t_r:
    b1 = np.array(a[0]) <= t
    b2 = np.array(a[2]) <= t 
    b3 = np.array(a[4]) <= t 

    ind1 = [(np.count_nonzero(b1))]
    ind2 = [(np.count_nonzero(b2))]
    ind3 = [(np.count_nonzero(b3))]

    x1 = np.array(a[1])
    x_mean1 = x1[ind1]
    x2 = np.array(a[3])
    x_mean2 = x2[ind2]
    x3 = np.array(a[5])
    x_mean3 = x3[ind2]

    x_mean_list = [x_mean1, x_mean2, x_mean3]
    x_average = np.mean(x_mean_list)    
    list.append(x_average)
#########################



no_of_sim = 3
counter = 0
while counter <= ((no_of_sim*2)-1):
    plt.plot(a[counter],a[counter+1], lw = 0.5)
    plt.plot(list, color = "black")
    plt.plot(x_average)
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('copy no.')
    counter += 2
plt.show()
```

The bit inbetween the hashtags is the bit I'm trying to write a loop for so I don't have to manually change it when the list if lists gets much longer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pythonic way to return list of every nth item in a larger list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403674/pythonic-way-to-return-list-of-every-nth-item-in-a-larger-list)

Comment: Can you try to simplify your question? You can use a simpler example of what you want to do.

Comment: Yah sure (the bits in bewteen hashtags is what im sturggling with): as the timepoints are not the same between lists (i.e. the [0], [2], [4] list in the lists of lists) , the bp and ind bit basically makes the first time point the same by marking the first element in that time list as true. It then takes the first element of the value list (i.e. the [1], [3], [5] list in the list of lists) and averages them, and appends the average appended to "list". It loops through a for the 2nd, 3rd etc element of each list

Comment: I just want it to loop through [0] to [2] etc wihtout having to type it out each time

Answer (score 1):

Your code between the hashes are equivalent to the following:

```
data = [np.array(x) for x in a[::2]]
idx = [np.array(x) for x in a[1::2]]

lst = [np.mean([x[(d<=t).sum()] for x,d in zip(idx,data)]) for t in t_r ]
```

Output:

```
[1.3333333333333333,
 2.0,
 2.3333333333333335,
 3.3333333333333335,
 4.0,
 5.333333333333333,
 5.0,
 5.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this code:

```
a =[[0.98,1.93,2.99,4.01,4.92,6.00,7.08,7.67, 8.00],[0,0,0,1,2,3,3,2,3],[0.93,1.99,2.99,3.91,4.82,6.03,7.01,8.00],[0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6],[0.88,2.09,3.01,4.11,5.65,7.12,8.00],[4,5,6,7,8,7,6]]

i = 0
for li in a:
    print("Mean of list at index", i, "is:", sum(li)/len(li))
    i += 1
```